# Liquibase: check if a property was set

Tags: liquibase

I could not find a way to check in a precondition element if a custom property is set.

What I found out about this issue so far is [here](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-939). 
As the ticket comment indicates, extending [CustomPrecondition](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/latest/api/liquibase/precondition/CustomPrecondition.html) will not help without modifying the API. Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) describes a **changeLogPropertyDefined** precondition.

The following example worked fine for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

    <changeSet author="mark (generated)" id="mark-1">
        <preConditions onFail="HALT">
            <changeLogPropertyDefined property="testing" value="1"/>
        </preConditions>

        <createTable tableName="TEST001">
            <column name="ID" type="VARCHAR(10)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="X" type="VARCHAR(9)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Y" type="DECIMAL(7,2)"/>
            <column name="Z" type="DECIMAL(7,2)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I run liquibase from Maven. The testing property can be set from the command line as follows:

```
mvn -Dtesting=1 compile
```

Comment: wow, I must be blind, don't know how I could miss this :) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @nansen The precondition name was misleading. I had to test that it worked for normal Java properties